# Unable to load the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse'

Tags: maven-2, maven-eclipse-plugin

when we are trying to run mvn eclipse:eclipse from command line, we are getting following error:

> Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse': Unable to
>   load the mojo
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse' in the
>   plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin'. A required
>   class is missing:
>   org/codehaus/plexus/resource/loader/ResourceNotFoundException

any help to solve this is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) is RETIRED:

> Users are advised to use m2e, the [Eclipse Maven Integration](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.m2e) instead of this plugin, as it can more closely resemble the actual build and runtime classpaths as described in the project pom.xml - among other advantages.